# Sans Fast Slam Attack Question

Tags: undertale

In [Bad Time Simulator](https://jcw87.github.io/c2-sans-fight/) section "sans_bonestab3", I used to be able to dodge consecutive slams against the same wall flawlessly. But after playing it over and over again in the past week, I can hardly ever dodge consecutive slams against the same wall.

Has this ever happened to anybody else, or is this something strange and unusual?

Answer (score 1):

Lore-wise, you're not supposed to dodge that attack. Sans gets desperate and does an unavoidable attack, but Frisk/Chara powers through by sheer Determination.